# Showing error while opening the json file in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have written the following code :

```
dataframe = pd.read_json('/content/tops_fashion.json')
dataframe.head()
```

But it is showing the error message as:
ValueError: Expected object or value[image]

I have tried all the methods but still it is not working . Please help .

Answer (score -1):

Use another notebook and try to run it again, i faced the same issue.